How can you handle internationalized queries with Elastic Search?
What functionality in elastic search would help query for a word spelled "Serialised" (-ised as spelled in the UK) with the Americanized version "Serialized" (-ized as spelled in the USA).
Is there any method to assist handling a query in a different language than the source text?
